# C Code NOP confusion

Tags: no-op

This file is in AT&T syntax - see http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/DM18/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm
and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax. Both gdb and objdump produce
AT&T syntax by default.

```
MOV $27163,%ebx
MOV $13156,%eax
MOV $25880,%ecx
CMP %eax,%ebx
JL L1
JMP L2
L1:
IMUL %eax,%ebx
ADD %eax,%ebx
MOV %ebx,%eax
SUB %ecx,%eax
JMP L3
L2:
IMUL %eax,%ebx
SUB %eax,%ebx
MOV %ebx,%eax
ADD %ecx,%eax
L3:
NOP
```

What is the value of %eax when the last instruction NOP runs?

Comment: I'm quite certain that your assignment is for **you** to figure out what the value is, not for us to do so. If your instructor wanted us to answer, he or she would have asked us directly. Please do your own homework. (And the next time you post here, use the help for formatting and the preview area just below where you're typing the question to fix the appearance. Your effort here was horrific.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "%933%". (no quotes)